# buffer overflow detected during gammu restore

Tags: python, linux, gammu

Having successfully backed up my Nokia C2-01 on Linux Mint 17 with

```
gammu backup my_backup_file
```

I was horrified to find that I couldn't restore the file. Doing

```
gammu restore my_backup_file
```

results in:

```
*** buffer overflow detected ***: gammu terminated
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__fortify_fail+0x5c)[0x7f2b8935408c]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x111020)[0x7f2b89353020]
/usr/lib/libGammu.so.7(LoadBackup+0x1e4)[0x7f2b89af7584]
gammu(ReadBackup+0x22)[0x42d552]
gammu(Restore+0x44)[0x42d784]
gammu(ProcessParameters+0x201)[0x42a261]
gammu(main+0x641)[0x40aa81]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x7f2b89263de5]
gammu[0x40ab35]
```

[This page](http://sourceforge.net/p/gammu/mailman/message/32317580/) looks extremely relevant, but how can I fix my backup file so that it will restore successfully?

Answer (score 0):

From [this mailing list post](http://sourceforge.net/p/gammu/mailman/message/32317580/):

> The reason is that the Creator field in the original backup file has
>   84 characters...[b]ut GSM_Backup struct defines field for that string as: char Creator[80];

The unbelievably low-tech solution was to text edit the backup file and shorten the `Creator` field:

```
Gammu 1.30.0, Linux, kernel 2.6.34.10-0.6-default (#1 SMP 2011-12-13 18:27:38 +0100
```

to ensure it is less than 80 characters. Then the backup restore works perfectly!